# Including default retained messages in Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Is it possible to configure a set of default/hardcoded retained messages to be available on MQTT when Mosquitto starts up?

I would like to use retained messages for app configuration in a microservice architecture to allow modifying and distributing configuration values on runtime. But I need a way of initializing the message when the app is started for the first time.

Another solution would be an application that checks for the existence of the message on startup, publishing the default message if missing, but this is not possible with MQTT since there is no `GET` or `EXISTS` operation. A workaround would be to `SUBSCRIBE` and wait a few seconds before publishing the default message if no callback has been received, which does not seem to be a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have enabled persistence and a persistence file, in the mosquitto.conf, to store the data in then any retained messages will still be delivered after a broker restart.

As long as you don't clear the retained messages (by publishing a message on the same topic with the retained bit set and a null payload) then they will always be there.

Comment: But what about the initial startup?

Comment: You are going to have to inject them once the first time. You might be able to create a pre-populated persistence file you could copy in, but I've not tried it.

Comment: Yes, and that is my question, how to inject them the first time.

Comment: and the second half of that comment proposes a solution, but you will need to test it first

Comment: Ok, so you would create a persistence file by publishing the messages to a local/developer machine running Mosquitto, and then deploying that persistence file with Mosquitto to the target environment. That might be possible, but I would be afraid of unexpected results since I don't know what other content is in that file, such as runtime/environment specific data. The persistence file appears to be in an undocumented internal Mosquitto format.